# Object php and json encoding

Tags: javascript, php, json

> i have this class on my php server:

```
class Voto implements JsonSerializable {
    public $voto;
    public $info;
    public $codiceFiscaleStudente;
    public $data;
    public $idProva;


function __construct($voto,$idProva,$codiceFiscaleStudente,$data) {

    $this->codiceFiscaleStudente=$codiceFiscaleStudente;
    $this->voto=$voto;
    $this->idProva=$idProva;
    $this->data=$data;
    $this->info=null;
}

public function jsonSerialize() {
    return get_object_vars($this);
}

}
```

the problem is that the script doesn't send to the client the jsonObject.I've tried to find the error: the script works fine because i tried to send back not the jsonObject but a single properties of my class Voto.

this is my other server syntax

```
try{
$query="LOCK TABLES sostieneprova read;";
$success=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if($success){
                $voto=getVoto($conn,$_POST['idProva'],$_POST['studente_codiceFiscale']);
if(gettype($voto)==="object"){
$voto->info="Esiste già un voto dello studente in data ".$voto->data;
/*if in my Ajax-request i set datatype="html" and i send back echo($voto->info) it works fine.Instead if in my AJAX CALL in javascript i have set datatype "json" javascript doesn't receveid a jsonObject but an empty string.i think that the problem is with the function below json_encode*/
echo(json_encode($voto));
}
else{
throw new Exception ("Non esiste alcun voto dello studente nella prova: ".$_POST['idProva']);
//$query="UNLOCK TABLES;";
//mysqli_query($conn,$query);

}
}
else{
     echo("Impossibile bloccare le tabelle per caricare il voto");
        }
        }
            catch(Exception $e){
                $query="UNLOCK TABLES;";
                mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                echo($e->getMessage());
            }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var ajax=$.ajax({
            url:"responseregistrodocente.php",
            data: queryString,
            type:"POST",
            datatype:"json",
            cache:false,
            ifModified:false});

            ajax.done(
            function(dettagliVoto){
            alert(dettagliVoto.codiceFiscale);
            });

            ajax.fail(function(jqxhr){
            alert(jqxhr.responseText);
            });
```

Thanks for help.

if this could help: in my html page i have a the jquery document.ready and inside that i have:

```
$(".submitProve").on("click","button[name='visualizzaVoto']",caricaVotoHandler);
```

then in an exsternal file i have the function with the ajax request

```
function caricaVotoHandler(evento){
    evento.stopPropagation();
    //here there is other program code to build the queryString and the querystring //send the data correctly to the server.I've verified
            var ajax=$.ajax({
            url:"responseregistrodocente.php",
            data: queryString,
            type:"POST",
            datatype:"json",
            cache:false,
            ifModified:false});

            ajax.done(
            function(dettagliVoto){
            alert(dettagliVoto);
            });

            ajax.fail(function(jqxhr){
            alert(jqxhr.responseText);
            });



        //}
```

}

Comment: I hope you UNLOCK your table also if the code doesn't throw an Exception? ... well did you checked firebug if thers an JSON message or not or how did you find out that PHP didn't send an JSON message?

Comment: i forgot to unlock tables but this is not the problem. There are no error with firebug; the text in the "allert" is undefined.

Comment: because the object dettagliVoto doesn't exist.

Comment: I know it was just an extra side comment about that UNLOCK statement. but did you check the net tab of firebug? because this sounds like an ajax api problem right now.

Comment: I have just add a LITTLE MORE CODE TO MY FIRST POST

Comment: here is what firebug net says: data send with ajax request to the server as i says is corrected this is the query string idProva=3&visualizzaVoto=visualizzaVoto&studente_codiceFiscale=LNFFRS93T09B157B                   so i try to see the html response and the content is empty. It seems that the echo with encoding doesn't send data and i have also deactivate all lock/unlock statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the script outputs properly if you only change `echo json_encode($voto);` to `echo $voto->codiceFiscaleStudente;` then your problem lies in your implementation of the `JsonSerializable` interface. try not using it:

If your class `Voto` only contains public members, all of which you are going to include in the JSON serialization, there's no need to implement `JsonSerializable`. Calling `json_encode()` on your object `$voto` will return the proper JSON string.

Also, in your first JS snippet, your alert call `alert(dettagliVoto.codiceFiscale);` looks like it should be using `dettagliVoto.codiceFiscaleStudente` instead, to match that property of your `Voto` class.

Comment: your solution doesn't work: i have delete the json interface but echo(json_encode($voto)) doesn't work. I have examinate the response via firebug and there's no text

Comment: I solved the problem: my file was saved with cip252 encoding and json doesn't work well!!! In order to solved this problem i have find on php a function calling json_last_error_msg and it says the error to me.